# paypal sandbox showing one product

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

This is my form view source ,

When i click on submit button

Redirect to Paypal sendbox and showing one item

```
<form id="Paypal" name="Paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<form action="/ShoppingCart/PostToPaypal" method="post"><input id="cmd" name="cmd"       type="hidden" value="_xclick" /><input id="business" name="business" type="hidden" value="anilcs_1361585097_biz@gmail.com" /><input id="no_shipping" name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="" /><input id="return" name="return" type="hidden" value="http://localhost:49424/Checkout/IPN" /><input id="cancel_return" name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://localhost:49424/SportsStore/CancelFromPaypal" /><input id="notify_url" name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://localhost:49424/SportsStore/NotifyFromPaypal" /><input id="currency_code" name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="2252330"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="122.75"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="51057"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="32.99"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="2252330"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="122.75"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="51057"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="32.99"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="2252330"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="122.75"/>
<input type="image" name="btnsubmit"  src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
    alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online" />
 </form>
```

Can any help me how i will show my 5 item in Paypal

Comment: Ok , Can you help me about how to show multiple product on Paypal using MVC

Comment: Hi Can you tell me , how to do this in ASP.NET MVC               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786608/adding-multiple-items-to-a-paypal-cart/11789678#11789678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected with the 'Buy now' button (cmd=_xclick).
If you want to display multiple items, you'll want to use something like this instead:

```
<form id="Paypal" name="Paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr method="POST">
    <input id="cmd" name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart" />
    <input id="business" name="business" type="hidden" value="anilcs_1361585097_biz@gmail.com" />
    <input id="return" name="return" type="hidden" value="http://localhost:49424/Checkout/IPN" />
    <input id="cancel_return" name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="http://localhost:49424/SportsStore/CancelFromPaypal" />
    <input id="notify_url" name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://localhost:49424/SportsStore/NotifyFromPaypal" />
    <input id="currency_code" name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="2252330"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="122.75"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="51057"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="32.99"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="2252330"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="122.75"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_4" value="51057"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_4" value="32.99"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_5" value="2252330"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_5" value="122.75"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="image" name="btnsubmit"  src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
        alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online" />
 </form>
```

In this, I have:

1. Added an "action" to the first `<form>`
2. Added input upload=1
3. Change cmd from _xclick to _cart
4. Numerated the cart items (_n)

By the way, I noticed you set your `return` URL to 'something/IPN'.
You do realize IPN is different from the `return` URL, right?
[IPN is an asynchronous PayPal server-to-server POST](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) which includes a payload about the transaction. Whereas `return` is the URL the buyer is redirected back to.
You set the IPN URL by populating the `notify_url` parameter (which you have done as well).

Comment: Hi Robert , I am happy about your post and now i am able add  multiple  items in my Paypal .. Thanks you very Much ..